# ios facebook get posted image by user

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

i dont know how to get posted images by user 
here is my code this return a username and user id, user images  but i want user posted images ,posted comment please help me

this is my code for only user information  and this is working but feed code is not working

```
if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {

    NSLog(@">>>> facebook >>>>");
    [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
     ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
       NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user,
       NSError *error) {
         if (!error) {
             NSLog(@"%@",user);
             username=user.name;
         //    NSLog(@"%@",username);
           //  NSLog(@"%@",user.id);
             userid=user.id;
           //  [self saviuserid];

       //      [self saveName];

             NSLog(@">>name>>> %@",user.link);
             stringImage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture", user.id];

             NSLog(@">>image link>>> %@",stringImage);

             // get feeds
             NSString *fdfd =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/feed", user.id];

                 NSLog(@">>fsdsd>>> %@",fdfd);




             if (checkfornextpage == true) {



             LoginViewController *flipViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
              flipViewController.getUserimg =stringImage;
               flipViewController.getUserName =username;
             //   [self.navigationController pushViewController:flipViewController animated:YES];
              [self presentViewController:flipViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
             }

         }
         else{

         }
     }];
}
```

Here i past a code this  is not working

```
NSString *fdfd =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/feed", user.id];

                     NSLog(@">>fsdsd>>> %@",fdfd);
```

now i am try this but this return data={} this result not have any information

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/feed"
                                           completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                                               if (!error) {
                                                NSLog(@"Resul %@", result);
                                               }
                                           }
                      ];
```

and the output is  make url and there have no data

https://graph.facebook.com/100005440749818/feed?format=json&access_token=CAAUTJQ2n428BAOlBQsZBhyMpac77tBCsFLBP3ud2Bj2yfX7caqJSzUJ76ljfuSrYNtyZBcOGSSdqHo9f7zarJ7YRKZAAbpMGjyWMcb5n0mggbYxodCuWBUnZBC1zvFppAt4ciAzgwUVQuGjXh7EUcBaZBxscQmkzaXOsYtcP5QrMh1p5y4hEZAXTdA6xOfDh9IJKLV7bKXUi1JHYfeH8SYT0CT65ww0YEZD&limit=25&since=1397743992&__previous=1

Answer (score 0):

**For iOS SDK info on making requests, see:** https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.1/class/FBRequestConnection#startWithGraphPath%3AcompletionHandler%3A

**So if you want to see say the photos for one album, given an album_id, you would use request code like:**

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"<album_id>/photos" 
    completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
       if (!error) {
           NSLog("Results: %@", result);
       }
    }
];
```

**Make sure you've asked for user_photos permissions first.**

Comment: i dont have a album_id i just want my latest posted images

Comment: First, you must have the right permissions, either "user_photos" or "friends_photos". Then you have to make sure that your test device updates your permissions -- I think restarting the device is what ultimately did it for me.

Once you've done that, you can get the JSON list of albums, after logging in via SSO, using this call:

[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/albums" andDelegate:self];